# Is there a way to extend a jQuery event handler that is already bound?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've written a code that clears the form on every reset event like that:

```
$("form").on("reset", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("form").clearForm();
    $("#reportGenerated").empty();
});
```

This code is inside an external js loaded in every page so this handles the entire system.

In one specific form in my system I have three inputs that loads Ajax requests into another parts of the page, then when I try to reset and clear the form the information provided by the Ajax request isn't cleared.

So my question is, is there a way I can extend my functionality above without being forced to copy/paste what it already does?

I've read the [jQuery Event Extension](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-extensions/) but does not seem to do what I need, plus, is quite "dangerous" to do it if you don't know exactly how every browser and its version handle JavaScript events.

Comment: Maybe just do `$('.container').empty()` on the containers where the ajax content is appended?

Comment: you can bind a new handler which will be fired after the previous one. Isn't it?

Comment: David, where do I place it?

Comment: A. Wolff, you say to bind a click event to the button that fires the reset action in the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily add another click handler with will run along with this one(no need to do anything in the already existing handler).

```
$("form").on("reset", function(event) {
    //do your custom stuff here
});
```

Comment: Arun P Johny, you say to bind a click event to the button that fires the reset action in the form?

Comment: no you can bind the handler to the `form` itself... a reset handler

Comment: Something like $("form").on("reset", function(event) {
    $("form").reset();
    // Do your custom stuff here.
}

Comment: Done. Worked just the way I intended. Thanks.